# Why does electron-builder fail with access denied error?

Tags: node.js, electron

With app tested in VS Code debug environment, the next step to produce Windows installable zip file by executing 'npm run build' fails during download of electron-v9.4.3-win32-x64.zip from github, with access denied error writing to local subfolder Local\electron\Cache. The npm log follows:

```
> alfatron@1.0.0 build
> electron-builder -w zip

  • electron-builder  version=22.9.1 os=10.0.19041
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=@serialport/bindings@9.0.4 platform=win32 
    arch=x64
  • install prebuilt binary  name=@serialport/bindings version=9.0.4 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=9.4.3 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  • downloading     url=https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.4.3/electron- 
                    v9.4.3-win32-x64.zip size=70 MB parts=8
  ⨯ open C:\Users\Hugh\AppData\Local\electron\Cache\644580475.zip: Access is denied.
  github.com/develar/go-fs-util.CloseAndCheckError
    C:/Users/develar/go/pkg/mod/github.com/develar/go-fs-util@v0.0.0-20190620175131- 
    69a2d4542206/fs.go:117
  github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Part).download
    Y:/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/Part.go:57
  github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Downloader).DownloadResolved.func1.1
    Y:/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/downloader.go:155
  github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/util.MapAsyncConcurrency.func2
    Y:/Documents/app-builder/pkg/util/async.go:68
  runtime.goexit
          c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1373  
    ⨯ G:\Code Development\AlfatronCameraType1\node_modules\app-builder-bin\win\x64\app- 
        builder.exe exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE  stackTrace=
                                                                                                                                                     
Error: G:\Code Development\AlfatronCameraType1\node_modules\app-builder-bin\win\x64\app-buil 
der.exe exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
                                                                                                                                                         
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (G:\Code Development\AlfatronCameraType1\node_modules\builder-util 
\src\util.ts:243:14)
                                                                                                                                                         
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
                                                                                                                                                         
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
                                                                                                                                                         
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
                                                                                                                                                         
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
```

The package.json file comprises:

```
{
 "name": "alfatron",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Proof of Concept",
 "main": "main.js",
 "scripts": {
   "start": "electron .",
   "watch": "nodemon --exec electron .",
   "reset": "git reset --hard",
   "build": "electron-builder -w zip"
 },
 "repository": "https://github.com/Hugh-W50/Camera_controller_type_1",
 "keywords": [
   "Electron",
   "Alfatron",
   "prototype"
 ],
 "author": "H Wylie",
 "license": "CC0-1.0",
 "devDependencies": {
   "electron": "^9.4.3",
   "electron-builder": "^22.9.1",
   "nodemon": "^2.0.0"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "electron-window-state": "^5.0.3",
   "help": "^3.0.2",
   "serialport": "^9.0.4"
 }
}
```

When examining the folder C:\Users\Hugh\AppData\Local\electron\Cache, it is confirmed that SYSTEM, Admin and user have no access rights restrictions, and each run attempt creates random numeric file name zip parts 1 to 7 prior to the failure; except for parts 1 & 2, these file parts are generally empty, or partly written at the time of failure.

Having launched the command 'npm run build' from various shells with the same outcome, some guidance is needed to overcome this issue.

Comment: I'm not seeing your issue.  I clone an [electron quickstart](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start), replace the package.json with the one above, run `npm i` in the folder created, and then both `npm run start` and `npm run build` work fine.  I'm on Windows, but the commands work fine both in Git Bash and a Command Prompt.  I suspect it's something to do with your setup for this project.  I suggest you try doing what I've done and see what happens. We're going to need more information to help you I think.

Comment: This appears to have been a firewall issue - but I had explicitly authorized electron-builder, and some of the download parts were indeed written. Perhaps it was a particular byte sequence in one of the sub-files that AVG flagged as dangerous, but that does not explain why the same authorization sequence results in electron-builder success today (as electron quickstart indeed also executed without hitch)!

Comment: After electron-builder success for my app and electron quickstart, the latter executes as expected once firewall authorization is granted (without needing to be run with Win admin rights), whereas my app (incorporating node serialport module) starts and immediately terminates, with no evident report of cause of failure. Firewall authorized, launched with administrator rights or not, from explorer GUI or directly from shell, leads consistently to immediate termination. How should I proceed to determine cause of failure? Do I need to raise this under new Stack Overflow question?

Comment: It's a separate issue, but I think you're going to have to do some more investigative work before raising one. There's not really enough information here to help, and Stack Overflow is meant to be a question and answer site for specific programming problems rather than general troubleshooting.

Comment: Having said that, it's not clear what you mean: do you mean `npm run start` doesn't even start your app from the command line or that having created a distribution with `npm run build` it just crashes when you try to install?  In either case you have a brute force approach: you've got simple code that works (the electron quickstart version) and you can probably work out what's causing the issue by adding in dependencies and code to that, or taking code out of the broken version.

Comment: Perhaps it is informative to note that subsequently the app (previously extensively debugged in this Win 10 environment) no longer executes as expected within VS Code test environment, due to refusal of localhost connection. I recall encountering this issue early in my VS Code Electron experience, but miss the remedy. Perhaps this provides some insight as to built app corruption of OS environment, since nothing else has been explicitly changed. Windows reboot does not remedy the situation.

Comment: My apology, I hadn't answered your question before adding last comment. As for electron quickstart, the installation process comprises extracting all files from folder 'dist' and launching the application executabie (identified with default electron app icon). I am unable to see it start in Task Manager, but it's run time may be too short to observe before termination without any trace of the cause of failure. Next steps should be to overcome localhost connection refusal, then test removal of node serialport (but no prior issues with this package).